Division by neural network; fixed value produced each time
I'm trying to develop a neural network to multiply and divide two numbers using this method. The multiplication part goes well, but the division doesn't - each time the program is run, for each pair of inputs, a small near-fixed value(fixed each time the program is run) is obtained as output. With the help of an answer on a previous question I asked (I'd recommend not going back and reading all of it, to avoid confusion), I made some progress, but have still run into problems, and thought it best to ask a new question. The code for my neural network is:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

num_train = 1000

X_train = np.random.rand(num_train, 2)
y_train_add = X_train[:, 0] + X_train[:, 1]

model_add = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(10),
            Dense(1)
            ]
        )

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model_add.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_add.fit(X_train, y_train_add, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)

a = np.random.random((2000000,1))*100-50
b = np.random.random((100000,1))*10
x_train = np.append(a, b)
#This is because previously there had been severe inaccuracies near 0, which led to problems during division, so I increased the training data near zero
y_train = np.square(x_train)

model_sqr = Sequential(
        [
            Dense(8, activation = 'elu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape = (1,)),
            Dense(8, activation = 'elu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)),
            Dense(1)
            ]

        )

batch_size = 32
epochs = 100

model_sqr.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer='adam')
model_sqr.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose = 1)

x = "n" 
while True:
    print("enter first num:")
    x = input()
    if x == "end":
        break

    print("Enter operation:")
    op= input()

    print("enter second num:")
    y = input()

    X = int(x)
    Y = int(y)
    Ydiv = np.reciprocal(Y)

    if op == "*":
        predicted_product = model_sqr.predict(model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Y]]))) - model_sqr.predict(np.array([X])) -  model_sqr.predict(np.array([Y]))
        print(predicted_product/2)
    elif op =="/":
        predicted_quot = model_sqr.predict(model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Ydiv]]))) - model_sqr.predict(np.array([X])) -  model_sqr.predict(np.array([Ydiv]))
        print(predicted_quot/2)


For example, on saving the weights and running the program, for each pair of numbers used, approximately -0.123 is obtained each time I run it.
In an effort to understand why this was going on, I ran 25/5, for example, with the program modified to show (25+(1/5))^2, 25^2, and (1/5)^2 too. I got the values 623.7364, 623.73645, and 0.24594116.
To understand why these values were obtained and how to fix them, I plotted the square function(orange) and my neural network model for square(blue) together:

Zoomed in close to 25;

Zoomed in close to 0;

The problem is, the intermediate values that I see were predicted from the plots aren't the ones I printed out. Using the cursor, I could see, for example, that 25^2 was predicted to be approximately 624, (25+(1/5))^2 was predicted to be approximately 634 and (1/5)^2 was predicted to be 0.42. Using those values, you would get an acceptable answer, but the values I printed out are different.
(1): Why are these values different?
(2): How can I make the model make the acceptable predictions the plot seems to make?

Can you share the closeup of the plot? the ones you shared are too zoomed out to tell what is the value with such precision

@BenetOriol: Which one do you need the zoomed up version of?

I don't see a reason why your plot should show different results than your script. Are you sure you are using the exact same model weights for both? I mean if you are saving your model after fitting and then loading the model before plotting that curve?

@BenetOriol: Yes, I'm using the exact same saved .keras file for both the plotting program and the script. The script I'm running to show the values is actually a separate program, not the one above; it consists only of importing the .keras file and then the while loop in the above code.

this is a model that is being trained to imitate these math operations, correct? I wouldn't expect the output to be exactly correct (off by a few percent is decent). You could probably improve accuracy by training for longer everywhere like you did for near-zero. There's also a limit to the accuracy based on the number of model parameters so you could also try increasing the size and number of layers in the model.

Try training the model on different numbers of samples (1000, 10000, 50000, etc.) and check if the accuracy improves with more samples. If it plateaus in accuracy improvement then you can add more layers and try again.

@IanChu: The number of training examples was already 2,100,000, so I kept it the same and trained them on a modified model of five layers, with 16 neurons in the first four and one in the last. Now I'm getting a pretty accurate set of values from the plot: 634.90, 624.85, and 0.1. These should yield a value of pretty close to 5, but I still am getting different values for each of these when I run the final script and the problem of the small, fixed number persists. What should I do to fix this?

@harry have you checked my answer about using just (Y * 1.0) in the reciprocal function?

I think the problem is that when you do the reciprocal of the integer value Y, it returns 0, so you are always calculating the product of X by zero.
Y = int(y)
Ydiv = np.reciprocal(Y) # Ydiv is zero because the reciprocal of a positive integer is zero

I think this is the main reason your program always returns the same result.
To overcome this situation you could e.g.:
X = int(x)
Y = int(y)
Ydiv = np.reciprocal(Y * 1.0)
print("Ydiv")
print(Ydiv)
print(np.array([X]))
print(np.array([Ydiv]))

if op == "*":
    add_predict = model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Y]]))
    add = float(add_predict[0][0]);
    msqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([add]));

    xsqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([X]));

    ysqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([Y]));
    predicted_product = msqr - xsqr - ysqr
    result = predicted_product[0][0] / 2.0
    print(f'result of {X} * {Y}: {result}')
elif op =="/":
    add_predict = model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Ydiv]]))
    print("x + 1/y = ")
    print(add_predict)

    add = float(add_predict[0][0]);
    msqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([add]));

    xsqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([X]));

    ysqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([Ydiv]));
    
    #predicted_quot = model_sqr.predict(model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Ydiv]]))) - model_sqr.predict(np.array([X])) -  model_sqr.predict(np.array([Ydiv]))
    predicted_quot = msqr - xsqr - ysqr
    print("result:")
    print(predicted_quot/2)
    print("---------")
    print("x + 1/y = ")
    print(add_predict)
    print(Ydiv)
    print("---------")
    print("(x + 1/y)^2 = ")
    print(msqr)
    print("---------")
    print("(x)^2 = ")
    print(xsqr)
    print("---------")
    print("(y)^2 = ")
    print(ysqr)
    print("---------")

I executed a 1000-loops run of your program for an x/y division giving results between 0 and 50, and the error between expected result and predicted one seems good, just there is an offset of 0.5 to compensate and some divergence for values close to zero


What should I use instead? As I mentioned in a previous question Ydiv=1/Y throws up a ValueError. np.power() does the same. '

I tried typecasting Y as float(y) and tried the above to the same results.

You can use e.g.    (see original reply for better formatting)
Y = int(y)

Ydiv = np.reciprocal(Y * 1.0)

...
elif op =="/":
    add_predict = model_add.predict(np.array([[X, Ydiv]]))

    add = float(add_predict[0][0]);

    msqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([add]));

    xsqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([X]));

    ysqr = model_sqr.predict(np.array([Ydiv]));
    
    predicted_quot = msqr - xsqr - ysqr


I added a plot of the model results:it can be improved but the results seem OK

I added to the add module two 10'000 elements vectors: one with range 0 .. 1 and one with range 0 .. 50, 30 epochs. Similarly, I added to the multiply module two 40'000 elements vectors with the same range as the add model. As you said, enhancing the resolution for numbers between 0 and 1 should improve the accuracy of the final result. Finally, I tested our model removing the cast to int for x and y and using x,y couples so that the division x/y won't surpass my training max range of 50, so e.g. a division 25/0.1 = 250 is outside the allowed range and isn't' considered.

It's still throwing a "ValueError: Exception encountered when calling Sequential.call().
Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank." because of the line "model_sqr.predict(np.array([Ydiv]))". Is there any way to fix that?

Hi, I had the same error while using your code; it disappeared after I passed to the square model the variable "add" taken from model_add, as you can see in my code above

Now it throws the error whenever I try division after multiplication(or vice versa) each time the program is run. Each time during running, whenever I change the operation I used previously, it runs into the error. I just don't understand the error, or how you managed to fix it, and why this is persisting in such an odd way; can you explain this?

Sorry, I haven't yet tried the multiplication part; I'll take a look, and I'll let you know

Hi, I tried the multiplication and it gave me the error you reported; I changed the code in the original reply similarly to what has been done for the quotient, it works without errors on my platform (with seemingly a bad accuracy to investigate)

Sorry never mind the part about the accuracy in my previous comment: there was a copy/paste error in my code, I amended it and the model seems to work fine

Thanks. Could you explain why exactly this fix works? I don't get why tweaking the code for the sum fixes everything.

Hi, it seems related to the vector sizes: sorry but I can't investigate right now, just as you said I tweaked the code to make it run

That's ok, thanks, just reply when you get the time
